# If $X$ is a compact CW complex with CW subcomplex $Y$, then $H_k(X,Y)$ is finitely generated for every $k \ge 0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, finitely-generated

> If $(X, E)$ is a compact CW complex with CW subcomplex $(Y, E')$, then $H_k(X,Y)$ is finitely generated for every $k \ge 0$.

I see that to show $H_k(X,Y)$ is finitely generated I could also show that $H_k(W_*(X,Y))$ is finitely generated since they're isomorphic.  But I'm having trouble proving that either are finitely generated.

I can see that $W_k(X,Y)$ is free abelian with rank equal to the number of $k$-cells in $E-E'$, but I don't see how I could show that this is finite.

Anyone have any ideas?

Definitions :

> $W_*(X)$ is the chain complex where each $W_k(X)=H_k(X^k, X^{k-1})$ and the $X^k$ are a sequence of subspaces of $X$, $\{X^j : X^j \subset X^{j+1}\}$.
>
> $W_*(X,Y)$ is the chain complex where each $W_k(X,Y) = H_k(X_Y^k, X_Y^{k-1})$ and $X_Y^k = X^k \cup Y$

Comment: What does your notation $W_*(X)$ and $W_*(X,Y)$ mean?

Comment: Also, $H_k(X)$ is not finitely generated *by hypothesis*. It is finitely generated *by proving it to be finitely generated*. If you understand that proof, then perhaps you will understand the proof that $H_k(X,Y)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have added the definitions of $W_*(X)$ and $W_*(X,Y)$ in the question.

Comment: And I see the mistake on that, $H_k(X)$ is only a finitely generated if it is assumed to have a finite rank, which I mistakenly assumed was true here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any compact CW-complex has only finitely many cells.  Indeed, suppose $X$ is a compact CW-complex.  Choose one point in the interior of each cell, and let $A$ be the set of these points.  Then since each closed cell intersects the interiors of only finitely many cells, the intersection of $A$ with any closed cell is finite and in particular closed, so $A$ is closed in $X$.  Since $X$ is compact, so is $A$.  But by the same reasoning, every subset of $A$ is closed as well.  Thus $A$ has the discrete topology and is compact, so it must be finite.  Since $A$ has one point for each cell of $X$, we conclude that $X$ has only finitely many cells.

Comment: So since $X$ is a finite CW complex, $W_k(X,Y)$ must be finite, and therefore $H_k(W_*(X,Y))$ must be finite and therefore $H_k(X,Y)$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the second and third times you said "finite" you meant "finitely generated".